# Eclipse with TFS plugin - looping login

Tags: eclipse, tfs, eclipse-plugin

few days ago (without installing anything new as far as I know) my Eclipse environment started looping authentiacation action when loging to Team Foundation Services. Everytime I want to explore, checkin and so on I see dialog "connecting to server" then dialog loading indentity providers appears and after it white blank screen and all repeats again and again.

I tried to find if I can reset stored password but there is no one in Credentials Manager in Windows (related to TFS address).

I tried update Eclipse plugins (ADT, TFS plugin) to latest version - same behavior.

Any suggestions or same experience

Kind Regards Jindrich Polenius Brezina

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that the authentication mechanism got broken during a recent upgrade of the service. It was fixed quickly, but due to the fact that you were unlucky enough to attempt to log-in while it broken I'm afraid that you are going to need to close Eclipse, delete all your cookies in internet explorer, close IE, open Eclipse and attempt to log in again.  Very sorry about that.

Comment: didn't work too. I have to enter liveid again but after succesful login loop continue...