# Eclipse with TFS plugin - endless login loop

Tags: eclipse, loops, authentication, tfs, team-explorer-everywhere

I have a problem in eclipse with the tfs plugin. I try to login and it stuck in some kind of login loop.

I looked here and in google. Nothing help.
I found this posts:

1. [Eclipse with TFS plugin - looping login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16642693/eclipse-with-tfs-plugin-looping-login)
2. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5e3f8b3a-d623-4401-b9f1-50f1f52ab299/eclipse-tfs-plugin-keeps-signing-in-in-loop-followed-by-there-were-some-problems-message

I tried to clean cookies and password and everything possible in IE
I reinstalled the plugin. I updated everything possible, checked for eclipse indigo last version (3.2.7)

Nothing worked. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Is this Team Foundation Service? Or TFS On premise? (if latter, which version of TFS?) Did you try removing your credential from the Windows Credential vault (control panel?)

Comment: This is Team Foundation Server

Comment: TFS plug-in for Eclipse 11.0.0.201303261635 com.microsoft.tfs.client.eclipse.feature.feature.group Microsoft Corporation

This is the plugin that I use in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

The forum posts you referenced are about the Team Foundation Service, not the on-premise server. Since the service uses Microsoft Accounts (previously known as Live Id's) it depends on cookies in your browser.

The on-premise version of Team Foundation Server uses your domain account which isn't stored as a cookie, but which is stored in the [Windows Credentials Vault](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/store-passwords-certificates-and-other-credentials-for-automatic-logon) by default for Windows processes. Try going through the stored credentials to make sure your username/password or TFS server isn't mentioned there. If it is, either update it or remove it.

Can you verify whether the same account settings are correctly picked up by Visual Studio/Team Explorer (if you have it installed on the same machine)? Eclipse and Team Explorer should use the same credential vault.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work.
I must say that when I try to login using VS 2012 it works. I think the problem is in Eclipse.

I didn't understand the question about team explorer...

Comment: Have you tried this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh190725.aspx#ChangeUsername

Comment: Martin (the primary author of TEE) explains that Team Explorer Everywhere 2012 should be respecting the Windows Credentials Vault: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11091733/736079.

Comment: What do you mean you changed the link to TFS?